# Number of distinct conjugacy classes of the multiplicative group of $3\times 3$ upper-triangular matrices with all diagonal entries $1$

Tags: matrices, group-theory, finite-groups, linear-transformations

Let $F$ be a finite field of order $q$ ; let $U(3,F)$ be the multiplicative group of $3\times 3$ upper-triangular matrices with entries from $F$ and with all diagonal entries $1$ . Then is it true that the number of distinct conjugacy classes of  $U(3,F)$ is a polynomial in $q$ with integer co-efficients ?

Answer (score 1):

This group has an interesting property (second, below): denote group by $G$. Then

(1) $|G|=q^3$ and $|Z(G)|=|G'|=q$; center gives obviously $q$ number of  singleton classes.

(2) Outside center, any two elements have same conjugacy class size and is equal to $|G'|=|Z(G)|$.

(3) With the help of (1) and (2), you can easily determine number of conjugacy classes in $G$, which turns out to be *very specific* polynomial in $q$; I am saying here very specific because in higher orders of matrices, the conjugacy class sizes *are* be more than two (i.e. property in (2) is *not* true for higher rank matrix groups)  and so polynomial becomes more complicated.

---

For (2), do following: show that center of this group consists of matrices in group with off-diagonal zero and top-right corner arbitrary (i.e. $a_{12}=a_{23}=0; a_{13}$ arbitrary.

Then take arbitrary element 
$$A=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & a & b\\  & 1 & c \\  & & 1\end{bmatrix}, \,\,\,\, a\neq 0 \mbox{ or } b\neq 0.$$
Try to find order of centralizer this element in $G$, and to do simplifications, we can assume that $c=0$ because we can *mod out* this element by $Z(G)$ (centralizer of $t$ and centralizer of $tz$ are *equal* for any $z\in Z(G)$).

You will see that centralizer has order $q^2$, hence number of conjugates is $q$ which is also $|G'|$.